# js why I get a differences between array written and created using same data?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Array, that works fine

```
var colors = ['#4200AB', '#000095', '#00ABFF', '#00C800', '#FFF800', '#FF7642', '#E40000'];
```

I'm trying to replicate an Array using variables:

```
var var1= '#4200AB';
var var2= '#000095';
var var3= '#00ABFF';
var var4= '#00C800';
var var5= '#FFF800';
var var6= '#FF7642';
var var7= '#E40000';

var  mysequence = new Array;

 mysequence.push(var1);
 mysequence.push(var2);
 mysequence.push(var3);
 mysequence.push(var4);
 mysequence.push(var5);
 mysequence.push(var6);
 mysequence.push(var7);
```

and I obtain same result and it's ok.
and with console.log I obtain

```
(7) ['#4200AB', '#000095', '#00ABFF', '#00C800', '#FFF800', '#FF7642', '#E40000']
0:"#4200AB"
1:"#000095"
2:"#00ABFF"
3:"#00C800"
4:"#FFF800"
5:"#FF7642"
6:"#E40000"
length:7
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

Now if I create my array using

```
var colori = Array.from({ length: 1 }).fill(mysequence);
```

as I need to replicate a specific part multiple times in future; using console.log(colori) I get

```
[Array(7)]
0:Array(7)
 0:"#4200AB"
 1:"#000095"
 2:"#00ABFF"
 3:"#00C800"
 4:"#FFF800"
 5:"#FF7642"
 6:"#E40000"
 length:7
 [[Prototype]]:Array(0)
length:1
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

As this second array didn't work in my project, I tryed to check differences using

```
let difference2 = colori.filter(x => !colors.includes(x))
                 .concat(colors.filter(x => !colori.includes(x)));
```

I got in console:

```
(8) [Array(7), '#4200AB', '#000095', '#00ABFF', '#00C800', '#FFF800', '#FF7642', '#E40000']
 0:Array(7)
  0:"#4200AB"
  1:"#000095"
  2:"#00ABFF"
  3:"#00C800"
  4:"#FFF800"
  5:"#FF7642"
  6:"#E40000"
  length:7
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
 1:"#4200AB"
 2:"#000095"
 3:"#00ABFF"
 4:"#00C800"
 5:"#FFF800"
 6:"#FF7642"
 7:"#E40000"
 length:8
 [[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

Where is my error? why I can't generate same array?

Any suggestion is wellcome. thanks

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: `.fill(mysequence)` puts the same sequence at every (one) position in the array. Why expect any different?

Comment: Your task makes no sense. You already know how to populate an array `mysequence` and now you're trying to create another array from that array... why? You already have one. Also why the `1` in `Array.from({ length: 1 }).fill(mysequence);` instead of let's say `mysequence.length` ? And why use `.fill()` ? `const b = [...a];` is all you might need to shallow clone an array. But again: [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: In my project I need to popolate an array dinamically; during test I just moltiplicated by 1, but I need to repeat sequence hundred times. What I did not understand is why my output between two arrays is different. At a first look seem same, but isn't. If I pass first array to a specific function (leaflet) works, but when I pass second, I got an error.

Comment: Maybe exist something similar to .fill(var1, var2, var3...) that pass a sequence of variables to an array, instead of passing (as in my case) an array to another one?

Comment: Thanks to you guys and your questions and doubts, I think to have found where a probable issue could be: maybe I'm generating a bidimensional array and not a "linear" one as when I create it passing variable directly to index? cound be o not? and if Yes how to keep it monodimensinal but genereting it passing multiple times same variables? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Night sleep gave me an hand, and found a working solution:
Instand of using

```
from({ length: 1 }).fill(mysequence);
```

I put everything in a loop

```
var  mysequence1 = new Array;

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  mysequence1.push(var1);
  mysequence1.push(var2);
  mysequence1.push(var3);
  mysequence1.push(var4);
  mysequence1.push(var5);
  mysequence1.push(var6);
 mysequence1.push(var7);
}
```

and result is what I expected, and work fine.

Thanks for your suggestions, made me think and learn